# Using Linq to get values from the Datatable columns in VB.NET / C# Winforms Application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq, datatable, dataview

I have a Datatable of items and their specific related data such as cost, tax information quantity etc.
One of the columns in this datatable is Invoice Number. The same value of the Invoice Number is repeated for all the different items present in one such set.
I have 100s of such sets in one Datatable.

What I need to calculate is the sum of the 'cost of Item column' and sum of the 'total tax on the item' column for each invoice number and update in the same table for all the rows that belong to the same invoice number. I will give an example to explain this below in the form of a table.

Basically i have been able to accomplish this by using for loops and data views etc. but by doing all that my code is iterating through the data table multiple times, which is hitting on the performance very badly.

I was hoping if some one of you would be able to help me with the Linq queries that I can fire on the datatable and the get the values in 1 shot, and update the same for all the rows in one single For loop.

Any other suggestion also would be much appreciated.

Please do not ask me, why is the data like this, and why can't we change the data structure, because we can not. This is a real world example, and all i need is a little guidance on getting the results in a single shot, rather that iterating multiple times in the same data table.

The problem is not with 10 to 15 rows, that is manageable, the problem comes when i have more than 130 rows in the Data table, that is when it starts impacting the performance of the code.

[Two Tables, Top one is Source Datatable and bottom is To be Datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFDkq.png)

Currently what I am doing is, I am first creating a temp table with unique Invoice Numbers.
Then I am looping through all the rows of my Data Table and finding the total of all the items and the total of the tax amount for each invoice from the unique invoice table.
Then I am looping again through the original datatable to update the total item amount and total tax amount for the respective invoices in the original datatable.

This is causing me to loop on the same data table multiple times, also i am unable to use exit for statement because there is a possibility that the invoice number can be present anywhere in the datatable, so basically for every invoice identified in the unique invoice table for calculating as well as updating the values back in the datatable i am forced to run through the entire data table.

Instead what I was hoping was, if there could be any mechanism where we can find the total of the item amount and total of tax amount for a specific invoice number directly and update it in one shot in a single for loop on the datatable.

I can do this very easily using SQL queries, but not sure how to write the Linq queries for this job.
The problem is this datatable is not present in this format in the database, I am performing a lot of operations on this datatable through my code, and this step comes towards the end of the overall activity.

```
Dim dv1 As DataView = my_format_dt.DefaultView
            Dim unique_invoice_dt As DataTable = dv1.ToTable(True, "supplier_id_invoice_number_combo")
            If unique_invoice_dt IsNot Nothing AndAlso unique_invoice_dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For row_cntr_unique_invoices = 0 To unique_invoice_dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    Dim unique_combo As String = unique_invoice_dt.Rows(row_cntr_unique_invoices).Item("supplier_id_invoice_number_combo").ToString
                    Dim total_item_amount As Double = 0
                    Dim total_tax_amount As Double = 0
                    For row_cntr2 = 0 To my_format_dt.Rows.Count - 1
                        Dim check_string As String = my_format_dt.Rows(row_cntr2).Item("supplier_id_invoice_number_combo").ToString
                        If check_string = unique_combo Then
                            total_item_amount = total_item_amount + Convert.ToDouble(my_format_dt.Rows(row_cntr2).Item("total_cost_price_of_item").ToString)
                            Dim cgst_percentage As Double = Convert.ToDouble(my_format_dt.Rows(row_cntr2).Item("cgst_percentage").ToString)
                            Dim sgst_percentage As Double = Convert.ToDouble(my_format_dt.Rows(row_cntr2).Item("sgst_percentage").ToString)
                            Dim cgst_amount As Double = Math.Round(((cgst_percentage / 100) * Convert.ToDouble(my_format_dt.Rows(row_cntr2).Item("total_cost_price_of_item").ToString)), 2)
                            Dim sgst_amount As Double = Math.Round(((sgst_percentage / 100) * Convert.ToDouble(my_format_dt.Rows(row_cntr2).Item("total_cost_price_of_item").ToString)), 2)
                            total_tax_amount = total_tax_amount + cgst_amount + sgst_amount
                        End If
                    Next
                    For row_cntr3 = 0 To my_format_dt.Rows.Count - 1
                        Dim check_string As String = my_format_dt.Rows(row_cntr3).Item("supplier_id_invoice_number_combo").ToString
                        If check_string = unique_combo Then
                            my_format_dt.Rows(row_cntr3).Item("invoice_item_amount") = Math.Round(total_item_amount, 2)
                            my_format_dt.Rows(row_cntr3).Item("invoice_tax_amount") = Math.Round(total_tax_amount, 2)
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            End If
```

So in my code, my_format_dt is my main Data Table. Using this data table I am creating a temp dt with only unique invoices. Then picking those unique invoices one by one, i am calculating the total item amount and total tax amount by looping through all the rows of my main datatable, then once I get the total item amount and total tax amount, I am again looping through the entire datatable to fill the values for each and every row that belongs to the unique invoice number.
Basically I feel I am looping around the main datatable way more that what is required. What is the more efficient way to accomplish this

Comment: "I can do this very easily using SQL queries" => have you tried an online SQL-to-LINQ converter?

Comment: No I am not aware of it. can you give me some URLs to start with. More over, since this Datatable is not present in the Database, I am creating it on the fly through my code, where i add about 23 different columns using the code, I have no mechanism to write the SQL query on it. I mean i hope you understand what I am trying to say, but I will give it a try by writing some dummy SQL and trying to convert it to LINQ

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336949/linq-group-by-and-sum

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I am sorry I am not able to figure out anything from it. basically, what I am trying to do is an equivalent of this SQL statement SELECT Sum(`col_name`) from `table_name` where `invoice_number` ='value'. Now imagine if this is what was supposed to be used, then I would have simple run a for loop in my main datatable, and selected one invoice number, fire the required query, got the sum value in 1 shot, and updated the same in the same row, in that same for loop. I hope I am able to explain properly

Comment: Just noting that Linq compiles down into loops. You may use it for clarity or simplicity, but manually creating your own loops should be no less efficient. Of course, incorrectly creating the loop can make it less efficient. But I see no code sample to see what might be wrong.

Comment: So you are trying to explain to me, that using Linq queries will not improve the performance because Linq queries are also going to loop across the full datatable. Right?
I am trying to put my code also above, so that you can suggest any improvements... Thanks

Comment: At the least, it looks like you can put the `row_cntr3` loop inside the `row_cntr2` loop, especially since the `If` condition looks the same. But you can also use VB.NET Linq like SQL, if you are so inclined, since it looks like you want to `Group By` `supplier_id_invoice_number_combo`. Consider something like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998258/datatable-group-by-with-linq-in-vb-net)

Comment: You have indicated that the source DataTable is created by your code.  Therefore you should be setting the column's [DataType Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?view=netframework-4.8.1) and there should be no need for code like `Convert.ToDouble(my_format_dt.Rows(row_cntr2).Item("cgst_percentage").ToString)`. Formatting a numeric object to a String just to convert the String back to a numeric is a huge unnecessary performance hit.

Comment: Thanks Michael, your example is exactly what I needed. That really helped as I was able to avoid a total of 4 loops through my entire datatable and therefore increasing performance. Thanks so much. How do i mark this question as resolved. 
Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi TnTinMn, thanks for the suggestion, but I do not know how to do that. I mean, I know how to define the double column in my datatable, but since these values are coming from CSV files, i do not know how to get these directly as double in my datatable. But still, since you suggested, I would definitely give it a try, and hopefully make my code more efficient... Thanks a lot

Comment: `these values are coming from CSV files, i do not know how to get these directly as double in my datatable` - You either explicitly convert the string value before adding it to the DataTable or you simply use the string value and let the DataColumn's DataStorage attempt to convert the string value (this works for all .Net primitive types that implement IConvertable and several other types).

Comment: Thanks @TnTinMn for your suggestion. I was able to do exactly as you said, and therefore eliminated all the convert.todouble statements from all my loops, but unforunately I do not see any noticable performance improvement at all. What am I doing wrong here. Any suggestions please...

Comment: @Ankit Srivastava, sorry, I didn't see the extra activity on this. Glad you figured out how to solve it!

It has no answers so far, just comments. If you like. you can add an answer explaining how you solved your problem, and then click the check mark on the left side of it to mark it as an answer.